# block is not working in magento 1.9.1.0

Tags: magento-1.9

**block is not working?**

/var/www/html/magentosample/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/helloworld.phtml

```
<block type="core/template" name="hello" template="helloworld/helloworld.phtml">
```

**it'execute in phtml file content to be display succesfully 
but i try execute the block to call this format**

```
<block type="helloworld/helloworld" name="hello" template="helloworld/helloworld.phtml">
```

**so its block not working with phtml file is not display**.

Answer (score 0):

Just wrong path:

```
/var/www/html/magentosample/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/helloworld.phtml
```

Must be:

```
/var/www/html/magentosample/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/helloworld/helloworld.phtml
```

Comment: the `helloworld.phtml` should actually be within the `helloworld` directory under the `template` directory, so the path should be `/var/www/html/magentosample/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/helloworld/helloworld.phtml`

Comment: Correct, my fault, didn't see it ;) edited my post.